# What user details are shared with publishers through Apple News?

Tags: ios, privacy, news.app

[Apple says that](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2015/06/08Apple-Announces-News-App-for-iPhone-iPad.html) “News seamlessly delivers the articles you want to read in a beautiful and uncluttered format, while respecting your privacy, because Apple doesn’t share your personal data,”. What user data is shared with publishers. It is the same data that iAd shares?

Comment: What makes you think any data is shared with publishers? Apple could simply scrape web sites and show you news articles without sharing anything at all. You might do all the sharing when you tap on a link to go to the web site of the publisher. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: On the Apple News Publisher website: "iAd provides campaign management, targeting and reporting capabilities that help drive your business." I want to know specifically what data is "reported" to publishers so I can make an informed decision on whether I want to use the News app or not. https://developer.apple.com/news-publisher/

Comment: Cool - it's always good to question and ask for details :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 9 Settings >> News >> News and Privacy, there's a long text that itemizes the privacy protections (and limitations) related to collection and use of individual and aggregated data.

Regarding "Disclosure to Third Parties", it says, in part:

> We do not share any of your individual data with third parties...

Comment: Nice catch @pseudon - I was about to post that here. It's a long read but quite comforting once I struggled through it all on the iPhone screen. It looks pretty consumer friendly and none of the iAd sharing is intrusive or something that you can't easily purge from Apple's servers when you wish to remove your history.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the publishers themselves don't have any access to your personal data. It's likely Apple News collecting info on what *Apple News* articles you read and like, so as to present news stories and articles that you might like to read in the "For You" section.

Comment: But why should we believe you - where has Apple stated this

Comment: I'm with Red Eagle - I see no indication that Apple shares any data with news publishers. They simply scrape selected feeds like a RSS feed scraper of old and parse, repackage it and present you snippets with the option of reading up more. Isn't this like an assistant going to the library and photo copying articles you might like and making you a daily briefing sheet. The publisher has no way to know you read their works under this model AFAIK.

Comment: @bmike Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Publishers get rich analytic just like any other web page you visit. The Apple News app is little more than a glorified RSS reader bundled with an in-app web browser.

In iOS 10, publishers will be able to distinguish Apple News users from other visitors to their website to a greater extent in iOS 9 due to [a new User-Agent](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/applenews-user-agent.html) for Apple News 2.